What is the prayer for money?
If I start a business or job, what is a 5 line prayer from bible or a song to chant 5 times a day to make money and earn and be rich? How can I boot strap after baptism? Jesus cures health is already experienced by all.

Christianity isn't about magic spells to make you rich. What you're asking is actually highly offensive to most Christians.

@curiousdannii, actually it is not. Jesus said to seek the kingdom first and all these other things shall be given onto us.

You should edit the question to make it focus on a single problem.

Gotta agree with @curiousdannii on this one; you can’t serve God and money - and God isn’t going to make you rich because you pray for it. Prayer must be inline with God’s will. That said, there are plenty of frauds out there who will tell you how to get rich by paying tithe to them and such. You must decide where your priorities lie: are you a Son of God who seeks to do the Father’s will? Or do you imagine God to be a genie - here to grant wishes for you?

What is so magical about the number 5?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany One of the reasons Jesus taught to seek His kingdom first and all these other things should be given to us is that to embrace His kingdom is to put money distinctly second to His purposes. In short: you stop seeking to be wealthy and start seeking the Bread of Life, having sufficient resources for your needs. I'm in agreement with CuriousDannii, it's a bit offensive for someone to ask how to use Christianity to set themselves apart from or above others.
